# Android: Retrofit2 stop sending request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-flow

I am working on an Android app. I set up Retrofit2 on it and after many trials, it starts working but for the 4/5 last days, I don't understand why the requests started failing.

Here is my code

```
interface TschwaaAPI {
    @GET("join/{joinId}")
    suspend fun getInvitation(@Path("joinId") joinId: String): Response<GetOrganizationResponse>
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesBaseUrl() = Constants.BASE_URL

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesOkHttpClient() = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS)
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
            Log.d("RetrofitRequestI", chain.toString())
            val url = chain.request()
                .url
                .newBuilder()
                .addQueryParameter("api", "api-key")
                .build()
            Log.d("RetrofitRequestI", url.toString())
            val request = chain.request()
                .newBuilder()
                .url(url)
                .build()

            return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
        }

        OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    } else {
        OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesTschwaaAPI(client: OkHttpClient): TschwaaAPI = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        // .addCallAdapterFactory(FlowCallAdapterFactory())
        .build()
        .create(TschwaaAPI::class.java)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesInvitationRepository(tschwaaAPI: TschwaaAPI) = InvitationRepository(tschwaaAPI)
}
```

The **UiState**

```
data class JoinOrganizationUiState(
    val newMemberUiState: FromNewMemberUiState = FromNewMemberUiState(),
    val error: String = "",
    val showError: Boolean = false,
    val open: Boolean = false,

    val code: String = "",
    val invitation: Invitation? = null
) {
    fun isError() = error.isNotBlank() || error.isNotEmpty()
    fun isCodeDefined() = code.isNotEmpty() || code.isNotEmpty()
}
```

The **ViewModel**

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(JoinOrganizationUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<JoinOrganizationUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        getInvitation()
    }

    fun getInvitation() {
        Log.d(TAG,"JoinID : $joinId") // This log is displayed but after this line, nothing is displayed
        viewModelScope.launch {
            invitationRepository.getInvitation(joinId)
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .catch { it ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error : ${it.message}", it)
                    var error = it.message

                    // check if the error is different than the ones from API
                    if (error?.startsWith("ERR") == false) {
                        error = "UNKNOWN"
                    }
                    _uiState.update { state ->
                        state.copy(
                            error = error!!
                        )
                    }
                }
                .collect { response ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "INVITATION : ${response.toString()}")
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val goResponse = response.body()!!

                        _uiState.update { state ->
                            state.copy(
                                code = goResponse.code,
                                invitation = Invitation(
                                    link = goResponse.link,
                                    active = goResponse.active,
                                    adhesion = goResponse.adhesion,
                                    member = goResponse.member,
                                    organization = goResponse.organization,
                                    createdAt = goResponse.createdAt
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        var error = response.errorBody()!!.string().trim()
                        Log.d(TAG, "ERROR!!! : $error")

                        // check if the error is different than the ones from API
                        if (!error.startsWith("ERR")) {
                            error = "UNKNOWN"
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "ERROR!!! 2x : $error")
                        _uiState.update { state ->
                            state.copy(
                                error = error
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

This log `Log.d(TAG,"JoinID : $joinId")` is displayed but after this line, nothing is displayed. That is why I think that the issue is Retrofit

The **Screen**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun JoinOrganizationScreen(
    joinOrganizationViewModel: JoinOrganizationViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val joinOrganizationUiState by joinOrganizationViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit, block = {
        joinOrganizationViewModel.getInvitation()
    })

    val context = LocalContext.current
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            if (joinOrganizationUiState.error.isEmpty()) {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = {
                        Text("Join an organization")
                    },
                    navigationIcon = {},
                )
            }
        },
        content = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                            )
                        )
                    )
            ) {
                JoinOrganizationScreenContent(
                    joinOrganizationUiState,
                    getInvitation = { joinOrganizationViewModel.getInvitation() }
                )
            }
        }
    )
}

const val INVITATION_STATUS_S601 = "S601"
const val INVITATION_STATUS_S602 = "S602"

@Composable
fun JoinOrganizationScreenContent(
    joinOrganizationUiState: JoinOrganizationUiState,
    getInvitation: () -> Unit
) {
    Log.d("JoinOrganizationScreen",
        "State: ${joinOrganizationUiState.isError()} - ${joinOrganizationUiState.error} - ${joinOrganizationUiState.error.isNotEmpty()}")
    if (joinOrganizationUiState.isError()) { // This is always false, 
        Error(joinOrganizationUiState.error, onTryAgain = { getInvitation() })
    } else {
        if (joinOrganizationUiState.isCodeDefined()) {
            val code = joinOrganizationUiState.code
            if (code == INVITATION_STATUS_S601) {
                FromConnectedButAccountedMember()
            } else if (code == INVITATION_STATUS_S602) {
                FromNotConnectedButAccountedMember()
            }
        } else {
            FromNewMember(joinOrganizationUiState.invitation!!)
        }
    }
}
```

This line `if (joinOrganizationUiState.isError()) {` is always returning `False` which is not possible because the test is done with something supposed to return the error `ERR_JORG_601`. The only way for it to return False is that the UI-state has not been updated.

The **Logcat**

```
2023-05-31 06:00:02.355 11248-11248 Navigation              com.tschwaa.mobile                   D  join/{joinId} - joinId Zc0ipNoaFaB-EtV1DsmIzOOWM1guMPTzDuhZfCZ2f3IwGzO6dYDruWDMJe6AdMFkmmL8YVmytIzSc0LbaiFYFA==
2023-05-31 06:00:02.370 11248-11248 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.tschwaa.mobile                   D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2023-05-31 06:00:02.376 11248-11248 .tschwaa.mobil          com.tschwaa.mobile                   W  Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-05-31 06:00:02.379 11248-11248 com.tschwa...nViewModel com.tschwaa.mobile                   D  JoinID : Zc0ipNoaFaB-EtV1DsmIzOOWM1guMPTzDuhZfCZ2f3IwGzO6dYDruWDMJe6AdMFkmmL8YVmytIzSc0LbaiFYFA==
2023-05-31 06:00:02.403 11248-11306 RetrofitRequestI        com.tschwaa.mobile                   D  okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain@ca0ed6d
2023-05-31 06:00:02.403 11248-11306 RetrofitRequestI        com.tschwaa.mobile                   D  http://192.168.43.32:8080/join/Zc0ipNoaFaB-EtV1DsmIzOOWM1guMPTzDuhZfCZ2f3IwGzO6dYDruWDMJe6AdMFkmmL8YVmytIzSc0LbaiFYFA==?api=api-key
2023-05-31 06:00:02.404 11248-11306 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.tschwaa.mobile                   I  --> GET http://192.168.43.32:8080/join/Zc0ipNoaFaB-EtV1DsmIzOOWM1guMPTzDuhZfCZ2f3IwGzO6dYDruWDMJe6AdMFkmmL8YVmytIzSc0LbaiFYFA==?api=api-key
2023-05-31 06:00:02.404 11248-11306 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.tschwaa.mobile                   I  --> END GET
2023-05-31 06:00:02.408 11248-11306 System.out              com.tschwaa.mobile                   I  [socket]:check permission begin!
2023-05-31 06:00:02.410 11248-11306 .tschwaa.mobil          com.tschwaa.mobile                   I  The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2023-05-31 06:00:02.417 11248-11248 .tschwaa.mobil          com.tschwaa.mobile                   W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getViewRootImpl()Landroid/view/ViewRootImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-05-31 06:00:02.417 11248-11248 .tschwaa.mobil          com.tschwaa.mobile                   W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View$AttachInfo;->mVisibleInsets:Landroid/graphics/Rect; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-05-31 06:00:02.417 11248-11248 .tschwaa.mobil          com.tschwaa.mobile                   W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/ViewRootImpl;->mAttachInfo:Landroid/view/View$AttachInfo; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2023-05-31 06:00:02.464 11248-11248 .tschwaa.mobil          com.tschwaa.mobile                   W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Canvas;->drawPatch(Landroid/graphics/NinePatch;Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Paint;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
2023-05-31 06:00:02.464 11248-11248 .tschwaa.mobil          com.tschwaa.mobile                   W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Canvas;->drawPatch(Landroid/graphics/NinePatch;Landroid/graphics/RectF;Landroid/graphics/Paint;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
2023-05-31 06:00:02.482 11248-11248 JoinOrganizationScreen  com.tschwaa.mobile                   D  State: false -  - false
2023-05-31 06:00:02.484 11248-11248 AndroidRuntime          com.tschwaa.mobile                   D  Shutting down VM
2023-05-31 06:00:02.485 11248-11248 AndroidRuntime          com.tschwaa.mobile                   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.tschwaa.mobile, PID: 11248
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                        at com.tschwaa.mobile.screens.JoinOrganizationScreenKt.JoinOrganizationScreenContent(JoinOrganizationScreen.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at com.tschwaa.mobile.screens.JoinOrganizationScreenKt$JoinOrganizationScreen$3.invoke(JoinOrganizationScreen.kt:79)
                                                                                                        at com.tschwaa.mobile.screens.JoinOrganizationScreenKt$JoinOrganizationScreen$3.invoke(JoinOrganizationScreen.kt:65)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1$bodyContentPlaceables$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:239)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material3.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1$bodyContentPlaceables$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:221)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$3$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:778)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$subcompose$3$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:446)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
```

How can I make it send the request again, please?

Comment: You have an awful lot going on in that function, it's no wonder you're struggling to troubleshoot it. If I was you I'd split out the functionality in to smaller functions that each perform the separate actions you're trying to perform.
Start by making the network call and examining the response, then add  everything else step by step. Name the functions according to what they do, this will help you understand the flow of events that are happening. Welcome to software eng

Comment: @IvanWooll I thought it was correctly splitting and also that I was following good architecture. Please, can you suggest to me how I can split them better?

Comment: I thought that's what I did in my last comment?